# PEGJS predicate grammar

Tags: grammar, pegjs, ambiguous-grammar

I need to create a grammar with the help of predicate. The below grammar fails for the given case.

```
startRule = a:namespace DOT b:id OPEN_BRACE CLOSE_BRACE {return {"namespace": a, "name": b}}

namespace = id (DOT id)*
DOT = '.';
OPEN_BRACE = '(';
CLOSE_BRACE = ')';
id = [a-zA-Z]+;
```

It fails for the given input as

```
com.mytest.create();
```

which should have given "create" as value of "name" key in the result part.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things here.

The most important, is that you must be aware that PEG **is greedy**. That means that your `(DOT id)*` rule matches ALL the DOT id sequences, including the one that you have in `startRule` as `DOT b:id`.

That can be solved using lookahead.

The other thing is that you must remember to use `join`, since by default it will return each character as the member of an array.

I also added a rule for semicolons.

Try this:

```
start =
  namespace:namespace DOT name:string OPEN_BRACE CLOSE_BRACE SM nl?
    {
      return { namespace : namespace, name : name };
    }

/* Here I'm using the lookahead: (member !OPEN_BRACE)*  */
namespace =
  first:string rest:(member !OPEN_BRACE)* 
    {
      rest = rest.map(function (x) { return x[0]; });
      rest.unshift(first);
      return rest;
    }

member =
  DOT str:string
    { return str; }

DOT =
  '.'

OPEN_BRACE =
  '('

CLOSE_BRACE =
  ')'

SM =
  ';'

nl =
  "\n"

string =
  str:[a-zA-Z]+
    { return str.join(''); }
```

And as far I can tell, I'm parsing that line correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the help, It worked. I din't know that pegjs is greedy.